# Samsung Galaxy Nexus Reboots

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, stock-android

I own a Samsung Galaxy Nexus and it just reboots every time after showing lots of crash messages.i tried to do a factory reset (volume button Combinations) using the boot mode, i was getting **NO COMMAND**. After lots of debugging i planned to re-flash the entire phone with the Factory image.Below mentioned are the details :

Product Name : TUNA

Variant :Maguro 16GB

HW version : 9

**Boot-loader version : PRIMELA03**

**Base-band Version : I9250XXLH1**

I tried searching for the binary and landed at yakju-jop40d-factory-279cdc5d where the build number matches but the problem is Boot loader is not matching.I am using the NEXUS ROOT TOOL kit for flashing the same .I tried to to see what version of the build is currently installed in the phone ,finally i got

**Build Number : JOP40D.i9250XWMA2**

Android 4.2.1

Please help me to fix this .

Answer (score 0):

Hy Try these links 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/help/galaxy-nexus-rebooting-t1591304
http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/development/gnex-toolkit-v11-1-0-drivers-backup-t1392310
regards
Stalin
www.memorylines.tk
www.facebook.com/memorylinesblog

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies.